# Change selection populating undesired results

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

I have two inputs. I am unsure what I am doing wrong, but I am simply trying to display the div associated with the input selection.

The issue I am having now is that if an input is selected, the console shows that both inputs were selected. Also, the title `.pg-selection-title` is not showing the correct data.

Why is my change selection now displaying the correct data?

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}

 $('.calendar-check').on('change', function () {
  if ($('#cal-2year:checked')) {
    $('#prev-2year').fadeBoolToggle($('#cal-2year:checked').length == 1);
    console.log('A selected');
    $('.pg-selection-title').html('A selected');
  };
  if ($('#cal-whiteboard:checked')) {
    $('#prev-whiteboard').fadeBoolToggle($('#cal-whiteboard:checked').length == 1);
    console.log('B selected');
    $('.pg-selection-title').html('B Selected');
  };
});
```

```css
.cal-theme-wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year">
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard">

<div id="prev-2year" class="cal-theme-wrap">
  <h4 class="pg-selection-title"></h4>
  <p id="calender-preview-choice"></p>
  <div id="calendar-select">
    A
  </div>
</div>
<div id="prev-whiteboard" class="cal-theme-wrap">
  <h4 class="pg-selection-title"></h4>
  <p id="calender-preview-choice"></p>
  <div id="calendar-select">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you also want to re-hide the divs when their respective checkboxes are unchecked? Always pass your boolean to your hide/show function, regardless of whether they are checked.

You might also reconsider changing the `.pg-selection-title` for both, in case both are selected.  Since the div will only be visible when that checkbox is selected, you probably don't need to dynamically change the text.

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}

$('.calendar-check').on('change', function() {
  // hide or show divs based on whether it is checked
  $('#prev-2year').fadeBoolToggle($('#cal-2year').is(':checked'));
  $('#prev-whiteboard').fadeBoolToggle($('#cal-whiteboard').is(':checked'));
  
  if ($('#cal-2year').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('A selected');
    // $('.pg-selection-title').html('A selected');
  };
  if ($('#cal-whiteboard').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('B selected');
    // $('.pg-selection-title').html('B Selected');
  };
});
```

```css
.cal-theme-wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year">
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard">

<div id="prev-2year" class="cal-theme-wrap">
  <h4 class="pg-selection-title">A Selected</h4>
  <p id="calender-preview-choice"></p>
  <div id="calendar-select">
    A
  </div>
</div>
<div id="prev-whiteboard" class="cal-theme-wrap">
  <h4 class="pg-selection-title">B Selected</h4>
  <p id="calender-preview-choice"></p>
  <div id="calendar-select">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code I am sharing is essentially what I made my example from. Both are supposed to be sliders. When you click on the slider image, a checkmark is supposed to show. Option A is in slider format...but the checkmark does not show. Option B is not in slider format, but the checkmark does show. Do you see why option A, the checkmark isn't showing? https://jsfiddle.net/wdw1a38c/1/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that even a jQuery selection that finds no results still returns an object.  So you can't just check for existence-- you have to check the `length` property to make sure it actually *found* something.

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}

 $('.calendar-check').on('change', function () {
  if ($('#cal-2year:checked').length > 0) {
    $('#prev-2year').fadeBoolToggle($('#cal-2year:checked').length == 1);
    console.log('A selected');
    $('.pg-selection-title').html('A selected');
  };
  if ($('#cal-whiteboard:checked').length > 0) {
    $('#prev-whiteboard').fadeBoolToggle($('#cal-whiteboard:checked').length == 1);
    console.log('B selected');
    $('.pg-selection-title').html('B Selected');
  };
});
```

```css
.cal-theme-wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year">
<input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard">

<div id="prev-2year" class="cal-theme-wrap">
  <h4 class="pg-selection-title"></h4>
  <p id="calender-preview-choice"></p>
  <div id="calendar-select">
    A
  </div>
</div>
<div id="prev-whiteboard" class="cal-theme-wrap">
  <h4 class="pg-selection-title"></h4>
  <p id="calender-preview-choice"></p>
  <div id="calendar-select">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem!  Happy coding!